# How to print strings in line in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

What I wanted to do is print strings in line inside a for loop, I know it is possible in python 2.x, but it doesn't seem to work for 3.x versions, so the question is, is there a way to do this in python 3 versions. To make it specific

```
user_input=3
for counter in range(user_input):
    print('| ')
```

what this code would give me is

```
|
|
|
```

but what i actualy want is to do something like `| | |`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
user_input=3
for counter in range(user_input):
    print('| ', end='')
```

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
user_input=3
for counter in range(user_input):
    print('|', end=' ')
```

Basically just have to add that you want to end the string with a space instead of defaulting to a new line when dynamically printing

Answer (score 2):

The [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has an `end` parameter in python3 that defaults to `'\n'` . If you use `print('| ', end='')` you will get the result you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this string multiplication:

```
user_input=3
print(user_input*'| ')
```

to get that output, which is simpler than changing the ending of print.

Comment: Thank you so much this is the kind i was looking forward too, i haven't thought it that way.